# How I can prevent Safari popups to increase database size on iPad?

Tags: ipad, safari, web-browsing, twitter

Recently I have been getting popups on my iPad2 when using Safari. They say:

> Increase database size?
>
> Do you want to allow "https://mobile.twitter.com" to use up to 10 MB storage on your iPad?
>
> Cancel Increase

where Cancel and Increase are buttons.

This popup just occurred five times in succession. I have seen it for Twitter (as shown here) but also (I think) for other sites (Gmail?).

Is there any way to prevent this? Or should I use another browser?

Comment: Yes. Increase the database size, delete the existing database (which will only grow back eventually), stop using those services, or install apps that make use of them instead of using your browser.

Comment: @cksum's comment would be better as an answer so it could be edited, flushed out. It's basically correct short of jail breaking and patching the browser code AFAIK.

Comment: @bmike In this case, I don't understand why someone would just not accept the DB size increase. It seems more like the answer should correct the question, not so much as answer it (I can't see a real need to avoid increasing the size of the database).

Comment: Therin lies the difference between the answer the OP wants and an answer that addresses the issue - but not in on the YES/NO side of the fence you might guess was hoped. Voting really helps in these cases, I have found. Would you prefer I answer this?

Comment: @cksum: reasons for rejecting the increase: 1. It is not explained why this is necessary. 2. That, plus the fact that it is unwanted, persistent popup makes it seem dodgy. 3. I hate pop ups and almost always dismiss them with Cancel. 4. Just to be clear, I *really* hate popups.

Comment: @bmike Yes, it's all yours. I think an answer should take a back seat to education on this one. Wikis, by default Safari allocates 5MB of storage space to websites. Sites like Twitter cache thumbnails, tweets, and other data. Hence why they create a local cache (not just a cookie). Gmail too. It's not dodgy if it's coming from a reputable website. Twitter and Google you can trust.

Comment: @cksum I'd amend that last statement to "Twitter and Google you can trust *to not deliberately mess up your browser*". I'm not sure how much I trust them in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to circumvent this behavior in Mobile Safari.

I know of no alternative browser that accomplishes what you ask, but perhaps if someone else does they will answer or edit my answer.

You can avoid those sites, or give more space when asked. It's one of those "we can't adjust the wind, but we can adjust the sails or steer the boat elsewhere" kind of things at present.

Answer (score -2):

If your iPhone is jailbroken Cydia has an app called AdBlocker. It's in the BigBoss repository & is a dollar or two to purchase. This blocks all popups on mobile safari, what it doesn't stop is the annoying "this website has an app. Do you want to download" message that comes up sometimes.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! You might be wondering why your answer has a negative score: this is because it has been downvoted, which is other users’ way of telling you they think you did not contribute a very useful answer. This usually can be avoided by carefully reding the original question and addressing that precisely. In this case, there is no reason to assume the OP has jailbroken the device (or wishes to do so), which makes a jailbreak only solution irrelevant. Also, carefully reading the comment thread would have told you this is not a classical popup issue.